# How to efficiently search in a database using a multithreaded scheme?

Tags: multithreading, performance, search, optimization, pthreads

I have a RAM based database in the form of a linked list of trees (Each node in the list points to a tree of strings). 
A set of words is given as an input and every word in this set must be searched for in the RAM database.
I thought of implementing a multithreaded search feature. The current implemenation uses a 2 level threading scheme. The first level class of threads will be concurrently taking words out from the input set and then each thread of this level will spawn other worker threads that will be searching for the same word in the RAM DB.
The implementation works but suffers a lot from synchronization overhead (Besides the overhead of creating, terminating the threads and the load imbalance between them) so i want to improve the scheme for better performance.
**Current implementation details**: The first level threads creates (spawns) worker threads to search for the same word. Whenever, one of the worker threads finds the word in the DB, it must kill other threads and then return the result to the parent thread (First level thread). The parent thread will grab another word and repeats the process until there are no words to search for. The input set is protected with a lock and every group of worker threads (Threads searching for the same word) have a protected shared pointer in the RAM DB.
The question is : What other more efficient schemes could you suggest for such a situation ?

Comment: Is this high-performance or high-throughput?

Comment: @DavisHerring It is a high-performance application.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the fastest is to have the worker threads already "running", but blocked on a condition variable (or barrier).  (If you know *a priori* how to load-balance the trees, the threads know which trees to search; otherwise, you need a work queue of some kind.)  The thread which learns the (next) word to search for then stores it in a shared location and signals the variable (or joins the barrier).  When one thread finds the word, it sets a flag that sends the other threads (who must unfortnately be written to check it periodically) back to waiting.

Comment: Here, you have only solved the threads creation and termination overhead. But the worker threads still have a synchronization overhead because of the lock they are sharing (To grab trees in the ramdb list). Actually, this lock might have a low contention factor if the search trees are big enough (One can use a spin-lock if contention is high). A problem with your suggestion is : How should the parent (First level) thread wait for its children (Worker) threads to finish execution ? Another barrier maybe ? Or a spin-lock ? but in the latter, the parent thread will hold CPU for nothing.

Comment: @KarimManaouil: There is no contention for trees if you can statically partition them among the threads, of course.  If there is never more than one hit for a search, the successful worker can post it, and the parent can just post the next word and re-enter the one barrier.  (Alternate between two word buffers/pointers to avoid stepping on the current word.)